# Bricked GRUB after deleting a partition on my hard disk

Tags: grub2, partitioning, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu and Linux Mint installed on my PC. Mint I bricked by removing the network folder in an attempt to make WiFi work.

I was trying to install MINIX when it asked on which partition I wanted to install and said it would overwrite the partition. It let me choose between:
h0 Linux
h1 Extended

I didn't know which one to pick, so I quit the installation and logged into lubuntu to check out my partitions. There were four partitions.
I decided to delete the one called Filesystem because I thought it was the broken Linux Mint installation. Lubuntu warned me though and said it was being used, so I quit the deletion.

Next I tried another partition. I thought this wouldn't be a problem, since there would still be a partition with Lubuntu.

So I booted back to my live CD with MINIX on it, and got presented with the same options as before. This made me think I might need to explicitly create a partition with a name or something, so I decided to boot back into Lubuntu. Instead of the usual screen with selection between Mint and Lubuntu, however, I was promtped with an error message:

error: no such partition grub rescue>

I'm now booted from my Lubuntu live CD.
The partitions now are:

Filesystem Partition 1 83GB Ext4
  Device /dev/sda1
  Partition Type Linux (Bootable)
  Contents Ext4 (version 1.0)
  In Use Yes, mounted at /media/lubuntu/[jibberish]/[my old username]

Extended Partition Partition 2 77 GB
  Device /dev/sda2
  Partition Type Extended
  Contents Extended Partition

Swap Partition 5 2.1GB Swap
  Device /dev/sda5
  Partition Type Linux swap
  Contents Swap (version 2)
  In Use Yes

Free Space 75 GB
  Device /dev/sda
  Contents Unallocated Space (Master Boot Record)

I've read about GRUB being the program that let me select which OS I wanted to boot into upon turning on my computer and that its files are installed in a partition.
There are people suggesting to use a windows live CD to install the windows boot program, but I don't have a windows live CD.

Is there any way to fix this? I suppose I could reinstall Lubuntu from the CD, but I've read that that won't fix the GRUB error.

Please help

Comment: Try boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2):

You can re-install grub by booting the Ubuntu live CD or USB and following the instructions on this page:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Hope this helps
Jim

Comment: Thank you so much! I am infinitely grateful!
My Linux Mint boot is gone now though, is this normal?

Comment: @user282335 Just to clarify, you have reinstalled Grub and Lubuntu is now accessible but Mint is not?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case.

Comment: I have another problem now though, it seems the partition pain never ends... Apparantly I simply had two partitions filling the entire disk. I booted into my live CD to use Gparted and make the space I had freed a regular partition instead of the subpartition it was. I went merrily on my way to install MINIX and everything worked fine, until I rebooted that was. Suddenly my computer wouldnt boot into anything. I decided to delete the MINIX partition hoping it might fix things. Instead now I am faced with the grub menu with only the Ubuntu and standard options.

Comment: Selecting Ubuntu I am greeted with an eternal black screen. I gave reinstalling grub a shot, to no avail. And even installed lubuntu a second time.

Comment: @user282335 Hi, that isn't sounding too good, in theory when you re-install grub it will search for any operating systems that are available, it may be that something has gone wrong with the installation of MINX or the deletion of the partition. Or alternatively it may be that the installation of Grub didn't complete as it should.

Comment: It's bad, I have to use my live cd now :(
I'm not sure, but grub still detects both Lubuntu installations as Ubuntu in its menu. When I select them and hit enter I get that black screen, and when I press ctrl+alt+del my computer seems to reboot.
Neither of the installations work, even though one is fresh.

I also tried restoring the partition tables with a program I can't seemt to find back. It told me the old Lubuntu partition was nearly full and that that might cause boot issues, but it has about 5GB left.